# WCF ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel Opened and Faulted

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, duplex

I have a WCF Duplex net.tcp binding. I create a client DuplexClient to comuunicate with server. If, for some reason the service stop responding (app pool recycles for exemple) between the client creation and the method call, I get a weird behavior.

```
try
{
    var result = await client.SomeMethod();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"client.State = {client.State}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Error : {ex.Message}");
}
```

I have this message in the console :

> client.State = Opened
>
> Error : The communication object,
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel, cannot
>   be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

How can the channel be in the state Opened while the error says that it is in a Faulted state ? I strongly suspect the ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel type because it probably keeps an open channel from server to client while the client to server channel is dead. Is it possible ? How can I check if client is realy opened and running both ways ?

Comment: No matter how you create your client, underlying it is an implementation of ICommunicationObject. You can cast the client to that interface and check [this excellent reference to understand it's state transitions.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/understanding-state-changes)

Comment: Already read it. It doesn't explain the error I get. It is specified in [this doc] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/choosing-a-message-exchange-pattern) that for IDuplexSessionChannel, there is a special mechanism but it's not explained.

Comment: In my experience, the State property is reliable until an exception is thrown. After that the actual state of the instance is faulted regardless of what the State property shows.

Comment: That is my observation too. Then I abort the client in the catch block to make sure the state becomes Closed